# Request.IsAuthenticated always false

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have problem with my application. I create empty project asp.net mvc in VS2017 with no authentication. Now I want to add registration to the app. 
Everythink works fine, but I have problem with Request.IsAuthenticated in _LoginPartial. 
I copied the code with the standard application ASP.NET MVC .
I try solution : 
1. Add ssl to apps - no work
2. Clear cookies and try open in other browser - no work
3. Add code to the webconfig :

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
 </authentication>
```

no work
4. Add  this to the webconfig - the same

```
<remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />
```

5. I try to delete  this :

```
CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
```

in Startup.Auth.cs
Still no work. 
Do you have some idea ? 
Thanks a lot